# how to add a foreign key that references 2-columns primary key with "limited length"

Tags: mysql

I have mysql database that has`parent_table` utf-8 with 2 columns(id varchar(14) , name varchar(256))
then I created a primary key for this table composing the 2 columns, but I had to create it with limited 200 length , -*because of a max index length problem-* like this

```
alter table parent_table add primary key(id,name (200));
```

every thing was OK , until I came to create a new `child_table` with foreign key references the parent, the child table has 2 columns (child_id varchar(14) , child_name varchar(256))

*NOTE : both tables are the same encoding(utf-8), same engine, same data type , same length*
although whenever I try to create a foreign key

```
alter table child_table add foreign key test_foreign_key (child_id,
child_name) references parent_table (id, name);
```

I always get an error of

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `mci`.`#sql-1724_3` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

then, when I dropped the primary key in `parent_table` and modified the name column in both `parent_table` and `child_table` to be varchar(200) and then created the primary key in the `parent_table` normally without limitation , as in :

```
alter table parent_table add primary key(id,name);
```

then when I created the foreign key in the `child_table` , **it worked!!!**

unfortunately , I can't change the name column length to 200 in my real database , because it is already stuffed with longer data.

**how can I create a foreign key in the `child_table` that references a composite(2-column) primary key in the `parent_table` with limited index length(200)?** can I do something like this ..

```
alter table child_table add foreign key test_foreign_key (child_id,
child_name) references parent_table (id, name(200)); // 200
```

Comment: Can you make SQLFiddle so that we can see your structure because this is only data type issue.........

Comment: @PiyushGupta [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/602e7/1) , **but I guess this link will not be alive forever** , so here is the creation statements `create table parent_table(id varchar(14), name varchar(256))CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
create table chield_table(chield_id varchar(14), chield_name varchar(256))CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
alter table parent_table add primary key (id,name(200));` , please note that this is the first time I use sqlfiddle, so forgive me if i missed something

Comment: As I can understand If you want to Alter parent_table then first you need to remove related foreign key constraint then should alter table and after modification you can apply same foreign key constraint again ............But make sure both data type should be same otherwise you will unable to apply foreign key constraint...

Comment: Are you using MySQL Workbench or terminal for alter tables?

Comment: @PiyushGupta I don't want to alter the parent , I want to add a foreign key in the `child_table` , that references the `parent_table` but I always fail whenever i do this > `alter table child_table add foreign key test_foreign_key (child_id,
child_name) references parent_table (id, name);`. and yes both columns in the parent and child are **identical**  , it is not a data type mismatch problem, I guess the prefix index on the parent must has something to do with the problem - and yes I'm using `workbench`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it, the answer to my particular situation is , **I can't**

as the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) says

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that ...

and it also says

> Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not exist

so what was happening in my case is that when I tried to create the foreign key, mysql tried first to create the index on the foreign key column, but It couldn't  *because of a max index length problem* , the same problem that happened when I tried to create the primary key on the `parent_table` , which forced me to create a prefix "limited length" primary key on the `parent_table`

```
alter table parent_table add primary key(id,name (200));
```

so , **I must** change the primary key in the `parent_table` to another shorter length column that does not require a prefix index, to give mysql a chance to create an index on the same column in the `child_table`

also there was an interesting note in the same documentation , says

> Index prefixes on foreign key columns are not supported. One consequence of this is that BLOB and TEXT columns cannot be included in a foreign key because indexes on those columns must always include a prefix length